# Hive: String split based on backslash \

Tags: regex, string, hadoop, hive

I have a table with column named `path` which contains values with backslash:

```
\ModuleCalData\ComputerName
\ModuleCalData\StartTime
\ModuleCalData\EndTime
\ModuleCalData\SummaryParameters\TextMeasured\Value
\ModuleCalDataSummaryParameters\TextMeasured\Name
```

I'm trying to split and access each element separately. The query is

```
select split(path,'\\')[0] from test_data_tag;
```

This query is erroring out

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   Error evaluating split(path, '\')[0]

Can anyone help how to split the string on `\` in hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select path
      ,split(path,'\\\\')   as split_path

from   mytable
;
```

---

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|             path            |              split_path             |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| \ModuleCalData\ComputerName | ["","ModuleCalData","ComputerName"] |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked :) But can you explain why 4 backslash are required?

Comment: Within a regex search pattern escaping is done using double backslash, e.g. `\\t` or `\\n`